# How to split all strings in a column of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataset with createdOnTimeZone and startDate columns. Timezones are like -600 but startDates are like 2019-01-28T19:50:27.345-06:00. I want to apply timezone to startDate in all rows. I know I have to split startDate on '.' (I don't need milliseconds, just until second is enough), use strptime to convert it to date-time and then use mktime to convert date-time to timestamp. But I don't know how to apply this on all rows in startDate column.

```
createdOnTimeZone startDate
-600              2019-01-28T19:50:27.345-06:00
-600              2019-01-28T19:50:35.493-06:00
-600              2019-01-28T19:50:38.947-06:00
-600              2019-01-28T19:50:49.048-06:00
-600              2019-01-28T19:50:59.600-06:00
-600              2019-01-28T19:51:08.267-06:00
-600              2019-01-28T19:51:15.899-06:00
-600              2019-01-28T19:51:27.326-06:00
-600              2019-01-28T19:51:38.762-06:00
```

Comment: can you please show an example of what you are expecting ?

Comment: @nassim For example for first row, convert startDate from 2019-01-28T19:50:27.345-06:00 to 2019-01-28T19:50:27 and then convert it to timestamp 1548705027 for all rows in column startDate. How can I split startDate from '.' in all rows of column?

Comment: How you get 1548705027?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.startDate.str.split('.').str[0]).astype('int64')//(10**9)`? Though I have no idea what the TimeZone has to do with this.

Comment: `df.loc[:, 'startDate'] = df.startDate.str.split(".").map(lambda x: x[0])` by this way you can split by `'.'`. Didn't get how `1548705027` you got this(the first 5 digits)?

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
df['startDate'] = df['startDate'].apply(lambda x : x.split('.')[0])
```

this will separate the strings by '.'

ex.

`2019-01-28T19:50:27.345-06:00` becomes `2019-01-28T19:50:27`

and this is for the time stamp

```
df['startDate'] = df['startDate'].apply(lambda x : time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(x.split('.')[0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").timetuple()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

a = "2019-01-28T19:50:27.345-06:00"

# Splitting the string and grabbing the zeroth index, which is the date.
date = a.split("T")[0]

# Similarly splitting and grabbing the time, removing the milliseconds.
time = a.split("T")[1].split(".")[0]

# Converted it to my desired datetime format and extracted timestamp out of it.
date_time = date + " " + time
time_stamp = datetime.strptime(date_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp()

print(type(date_time), date_time)
print(type(time_stamp), time_stamp)
```

- Output:

```
<class 'str'> 2019-01-28 19:50:27
<class 'float'> 1548726627.0
```